# Python FTP grabbing and saving images issue

Tags: python, image, ftp

**EDIT: I got it working it just won't download anything...**

So here is my code simplified now:

```
notions_ftp = ftplib.FTP(ftp_host, ftp_user, ftp_passwd)
folder = "Leisure Arts - Images"
notions_ftp.cwd(folder)
image = open("015693PR-com.jpg","wb")
notions_ftp.retrlines("RETR 015693PR-com.jpg", image.write)
send_image = open("015693PR-com.jpg", 'r')
```

And Here is my output:

```
'250 "/Leisure Arts - Images": is current directory.'
'226 Transfer complete. 0 bytes in 0.00 sec. (0.000 Kb/s)'
```

**Original Post:**
OK So I have been messing with this all day long. I am fairly new to Python FTP. So I have searched through here and came up w/ this:

```
images = notions_ftp.nlst()
    for image_name in image_names:
        if found_url == False:
            try:
                for image in images:
                    ftp_image_name = "./%s" % image_name
                    if ftp_image_name == image:
                        found_url = True
                        image_name_we_want = image_name
            except:
                pass

    # We failed to find an image for this product, it will have to be done manually
    if found_url == False:
        log.info("Image ain't there baby -- SKU: %s" % sku)
        return False
    # Hey we found something! Open the image....
    notions_ftp.retrlines("RETR %s" % image_name_we_want, open(image_name_we_want, "rb"))
    1/0
```

So I have narrowed the error down to the line before I divide by zero. Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 6, in <module>
  File "<console>", line 39, in insert_image
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '411483CC-IT,IM.jpg'
```

So if you follow the code you will see that the image IS in the directory because image_name_we_want is set if found in that directory listing on the first line of my code. And I KNOW it's there because I am looking at the FTP site myself and ...it's freakin there. So at some point during all of this I got the image to save locally, which is most desired, but I have long since forgot what I used to make it do that. Either way, why does it think that the image isn't there when it clearly finds it in the listing.

OK so I took the suggestion and now I get:

```
14:01:18,057 ERROR [pylons-admin] Image to big or corrupt! Skipping Image for product sku: 411483
14:01:18,057 ERROR [pylons-admin] Image to big or corrupt! Skipping Image for product sku: 411483
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 6, in <module>
  File "<console>", line 40, in insert_image
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/ftplib.py", line 418, in retrlines
    callback(line)
TypeError: 'file' object is not callable
>>> 14:01:24,694 INFO  [pylons-admin] Script Done! Updated 0 Products w/ Images
```

So it got the first image, which I think really is corrupt, but then when it goes on to the next one to be processed it throws that error on the file object. So here is how I changed it and the rest of the code not put here in the first place:

```
# Hey we found something! Open the image....
    f = open(image_name_we_want, "wb")
    notions_ftp.retrlines("RETR %s" % image_name_we_want, f)
    send_image = open(image_name_we_want, 'r')

    # ...and send it for processing
    try:
        image_id = product_obj.set_image(send_image, 5, 1)
    except IOError, error:
        log.error("Image to big or corrupt! Skipping Image for product sku: %s" % sku)
        image_id = False
    else:
        if image_id == False:
            log.error("Could not Insert the image for product sku: %s" % sku)
            f.close()
            return False
        else:
            f.close()
            os.remove(image_name_we_want)
            return True
```

Comment: I have modified your original code, it should work now :)

Comment: @PylonsN00b: is it working now?

Comment: OH wow I haven't seen, I will check tonight I gave up for a while.

Comment: @PylonsN00b: I've edited  the first part, it now says `image.write` instead of `image.write()` which doesn't work.

PS: use @username to get someone's attention, otherwise they might not notice ;)

Comment: @WoLpH Thanks man, giving it a try right now...

Comment: @WoLpH...I still just get blank images, I have downloaded them all and going to process them locally, thanks for hanging in there with me though I really appreciate it. I think the FTP site is the problem.

Comment: @PylonsN00b: I've only just now noticed that instead of using `retrbinary` you're using `retrlines`. That works perfectly for text files, but less so for images.

Comment: @WoLpH yeah I tried that too, I just get blank files, it's lame. The script is shot to hell now because I did so much debuging I lost all original logic. I am just going to do it locally, I would love to geek out and keep trucking at it, but business doesn't approve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're reading the file instead of writing it.

So instead of `open(image_name_we_want, "rb")` use `open(image_name_we_want, "wb")`

[edit]
If you're simply fetching from an ftp server than you could also try this:

```
import urllib2
fh = urllib2.urlopen('ftp://server/path/file.png')
file('file.png', 'wb').write(fh.read())
```

Also, for a fully working example read this: http://docs.python.org/library/ftplib.html

You're also missing the `write` after the `open()`

Comment: should I be using RETR or STOR?

Comment: `RETR` is for downloading from the FTP server. `STOR` is for uploading.

Comment: well dangit that is so much easier, and that is what I was using with similar code to get from an http url.

Comment: well this would be great if the ftp didn't require a login, I am working on it though

Comment: That's also an option, just use `ftp://user:password@server/path/file.png`

Comment: I think it just has some personal vendetta against me